# How to use MapBox NavigationView inside a fragment

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Based on the changes that has been introduced in 0.7.0, I need to make use of turn-by-turn navigation drop-in UI, however inside my fragment, so I need help trying to figure out how to do so as the documentation to implement `NavigationView` is based on Activity, such as the life cycle callbacks which are different in the case of fragments

The reason why I need to make use of the drop-in UI inside my fragment is because my fragment is in a tab control, and is already handling some custom location based features, and needs to show a turn-by-turn navigation when needed

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the NavigationLauncher, which will create its own full screen activity on the fly, or you can create your own NavigationView fragment. I preferred the latter option, as then, I could embed the fragment into my tabbed container.

The full instructions are located [here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/navigation-ui/#navigationview-fragment-example).